# Смена цвета кнопки при нажатии

Tags: java, javafx

Возник такой вопрос как заменить цвет кнопки при нажатии?
Кнопки я получаю в цикле, вот код:

```
 public void drawGenre() {
    Set<Genre> genres = GenreController.getGenres();

    for (Genre genre : genres) {
        flowPaneTop.getChildren().add(getButtonForGenre(genre.getName()));
    }

}

private Button getButtonForGenre(String nameGenre) {
    Button buttonGenre = new Button(nameGenre);
    buttonGenre.getStyleClass().add("buttonGenre");
buttonGenre.setOnAction(e->buttonGenre.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #a23535"));
    return buttonGenre;
}
```

Но если написать так, как выше, то когда нажимаю на первую, а потом на вторую, третью и т.д прежние копки остаются выделенными тоже, а нужно что-бы только одна. Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете стиль в первую кнопку, когда нажимаете 2-ю то стиль добавляется туда,а из первой кнопки то стиль никто не удалил

вам надо удалять стиль из первой кнопки

если вы хотите сделать несколько кнопок по типу поведения похожих на радио кнопки то используйте ToggleButton и ToggleGroup (про группы и кнопки [Тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462754/togglegroup-with-togglebuttons-javafx))

Comment: А как удалить стиль из предыдущей кнопки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759310/how-to-reset-back-to-default-css-after-adding-style попробуйте, там похожая проблема со сбросом стиля